# Fastest way for boolean matrix computations

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a boolean matrix with **`1.5E6`** rows and **`20E3`** columns, similar to this example:

```
M = [[ True,  True, False,  True, ...],
     [False,  True,  True,  True, ...],
     [False, False, False, False, ...],
     [False,  True, False, False, ...],
     ...
     [ True,  True, False, False, ...]
     ]
```

Also, I have another matrix **`N`** ( `1.5E6` rows, `1` column):

```
 N = [[ True],
      [False],
      [ True],
      [ True],
      ...
      [ True]
      ]
```

What I need to do, is to go through each column pair from matrix `M` (1&1, 1&2, 1&3, 1&N, 2&1, 2&2 etc) combined by the `AND` operator, and count how many overlaps there are between the result and matrix `N`.

My Python/Numpy code would look like this:

```
for i in range(M.shape[1]):
  for j in range(M.shape[1]):
    result = M[:,i] & M[:,j] # Combine the columns with AND operator
    count = np.sum(result & N.ravel()) # Counts the True occurrences
    ... # Save the count for the i and j pair
```

The problem is, going through `20E3 x 20E3` combinations with two for loops is computationally expensive (***takes around* 5-10 days *to compute***). A better option I tried is comparing each column to the whole matrix M:

```
for i in range(M.shape[1]):
  result = M[:,i]*M.shape[1] & M # np.tile or np.repeat is used to horizontally repeat the column
  counts = np.sum(result & N*M.shape[1], axis=0)
  ... # Save the counts
```

This reduces overhead and calculation time to around 10%, but it's ***still taking* 1 day or so *to compute.***

**My question would be** :
what is the fastest way (non Python maybe?) to make these calculations (basically just `AND` and `SUM`)?

I was thinking about low level languages, GPU processing, quantum computing etc.. but I don't know much about any of these so any advice regarding the direction is appreciated!

**Additional thoughts:**
Currently thinking if there is a fast way using the dot product (as Davikar proposed) for computing triplets of combinations:

```
def compute(M, N):
    out = np.zeros((M.shape[1], M.shape[1], M.shape[1]), np.int32)
    for i in range(M.shape[1]):
        for j in range(M.shape[1]):
            for k in range(M.shape[1]):
                result = M[:, i] & M[:, j] & M[:, k]
                out[i, j, k] = np.sum(result & N.ravel())
    return out
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the `tensorflow` tag in the question? When you say "1.5mm", is that 1.5 million rows? Just to clarify. Also, what do you do with `count`? Are you accumulating the total sum, or each `count` is stored individually, or something else?

Comment: None of the tags are too relevant since it's just a theoretical question. Let me know if there are better tags. 1.5 million rows, yes. I am storing the count of True occurrences, np.sum is returning the count for a bool array.

Comment: Yes but I meant, all of the `count` values should be summed into a global total, or the `count` for each pair of columns should be stored separately? (in your loops, you are just replacing the value of `count` in each iteration, so I'm not sure if you do something else with it later or just accumulate it).

Comment: So i put dot dot dot, this is exactly what I'm doing after, basically storing the count per i and j pair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to get all the counts -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik,i->jk',M,M.astype(int),N.ravel())
```

Feel free to play around with `optimize` flag with `np.einsum`. Also, feel free to play around with different dtypes conversion.

To leverage GPU, we can use `tensorflow` package that also supports [`einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum).

**Faster alternatives with `np.dot` :**

```
(M&N).T.dot(M.astype(int))
(M&N).T.dot(M.astype(np.float32))
```

**Timings -**

```
In [110]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: M = np.random.rand(500,300)>0.5
     ...: N = np.random.rand(500,1)>0.5

In [111]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ik,i->jk',M,M.astype(int),N.ravel())
     ...: %timeit (M&N).T.dot(M.astype(int))
     ...: %timeit (M&N).T.dot(M.astype(np.float32))
227 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
66.8 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
3.26 ms ± 753 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And take it a bit further with float32 conversions for both of the boolean arrays -

```
In [122]: %%timeit
     ...: p1 = (M&N).astype(np.float32)
     ...: p2 = M.astype(np.float32)
     ...: out = p1.T.dot(p2)
2.7 ms ± 34.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This is very much appreciated! Seems to work in theory, but somehow counts are higher than expected: https://repl.it/repls/PlainUnwieldyCurrency

Comment: @FrancWeser When you say `results are higher`, do you mean the counts are larger than the ones that you are getting from your loop based solution(s)?

Comment: Yes. Are you able to open the code snippet that I posted? Have written out both versions

Comment: @FrancWeser Well theoretically this should work. I have also tested with a random data of `(500,300)` and that worked too. Are you sure you have checked it properly. How are you checking again?

Comment: I made the mistake that np.sum(result & N) should have been np.sum(result & N.ravel()). Intended count is of 1D array AND 1D array, not 1D array AND 2D array. Is there an easy fix to translate it into your code? Sorry!

Comment: Hey, I added a paragraph to the initial question, something I'm currently trying to figure out. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: @FrancWeser Yeah, just add one more arg for `M` in `einsum` : `np.einsum('ij,ik,il,i->jkl',M,M,M.astype(int),N.ravel())`.

Comment: Simpler than I thought! I'm wondering if it works also for dot product, since it's the fastest solution for the 2D way

Comment: @FrancWeser Well sadly `np.dot` accepts two arguments only. So, we could work with two matrices as was the case before. With three versions of M as needed for the edited code, we don't have a good way. Think that einsum is the best you can do there.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: To fix the code below to the fit the corrected question, just a couple of minor changes are required in `compute`:

```
def compute(m, n):
    m = np.asarray(m)
    n = np.asarray(n)
    # Apply mask N in advance
    m2 = m & n
    # Pack booleans into uint8 for more efficient bitwise operations
    # Also transpose for better caching (maybe?)
    mb = np.packbits(m2.T, axis=1)
    # Table with number of ones in each uint8
    num_bits = (np.arange(256)[:, np.newaxis] & (1 << np.arange(8))).astype(bool).sum(1)
    # Allocate output array
    out = np.zeros((m2.shape[1], m2.shape[1]), np.int32)
    # Do the counting with Numba
    _compute_nb(mb, num_bits, out)
    # Make output symmetric
    out = out + out.T
    # Add values in diagonal
    out[np.diag_indices_from(out)] = m2.sum(0)
    # Scale by number of ones in n
    return out
```

---

I would do this with Numba, using a few tricks. First, you can do only half of the column-wise operations, since the other half is repeated. Second, you can pack the boolean values into bytes so with each `&` you are operating over eight values instead of one. Third, you can use multiprocessing to parallelize it. In total, you could do it like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def compute(m, n):
    m = np.asarray(m)
    n = np.asarray(n)
    # Pack booleans into uint8 for more efficient bitwise operations
    # Also transpose for better caching (maybe?)
    mb = np.packbits(m.T, axis=1)
    # Table with number of ones in each uint8
    num_bits = (np.arange(256)[:, np.newaxis] & (1 << np.arange(8))).astype(bool).sum(1)
    # Allocate output array
    out = np.zeros((m.shape[1], m.shape[1]), np.int32)
    # Do the counting with Numba
    _compute_nb(mb, num_bits, out)
    # Make output symmetric
    out = out + out.T
    # Add values in diagonal
    out[np.diag_indices_from(out)] = m.sum(0)
    # Scale by number of ones in n
    out *= n.sum()
    return out

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def _compute_nb(mb, num_bits, out):
    # Go through each pair of columns without repetitions
    for i in nb.prange(mb.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in nb.prange(1, mb.shape[0]):
            # Count common bits
            v = 0
            for k in range(mb.shape[1]):
                v += num_bits[mb[i, k] & mb[j, k]]
            out[i, j] = v

# Test
m = np.array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
              [False,  True,  True,  True],
              [False, False, False, False],
              [False,  True, False, False],
              [ True,  True, False, False]])
n = np.array([[ True],
              [False],
              [ True],
              [ True],
              [ True]])
out = compute(m, n)
print(out)
# [[ 8  8  0  4]
#  [ 8 16  4  8]
#  [ 0  4  4  4]
#  [ 4  8  4  8]]
```

As a quick comparison, here is a small benchmark against the original loop and NumPy-only  methods (I am pretty sure the proposals by Divakar are the best you can get from NumPy):

```py
import numpy as np

# Original loop

def compute_loop(m, n):
    out = np.zeros((m.shape[1], m.shape[1]), np.int32)
    for i in range(m.shape[1]):
        for j in range(m.shape[1]):
            result = m[:, i] & m[:, j]
            out[i, j] = np.sum(result & n)
    return out

# Divakar methods

def compute2(m, n):
    return np.einsum('ij,ik,lm->jk', m, m.astype(int), n)

def compute3(m, n):
    return np.einsum('ij,ik->jk',m, m.astype(int)) * n.sum()

def compute4(m, n):
    return np.tensordot(m, m.astype(int),axes=((0,0))) * n.sum()

def compute5(m, n):
    return m.T.dot(m.astype(int))*n.sum()

# Make random data
np.random.seed(0)
m = np.random.rand(1000, 100) > .5
n = np.random.rand(1000, 1) > .5
print(compute(m, n).shape)
# (100, 100)

%timeit compute(m, n)
# 768 µs ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit compute_loop(m, n)
# 11 s ± 1.23 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit compute2(m, n)
# 7.65 s ± 1.06 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit compute3(m, n)
# 23.5 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit compute4(m, n)
# 8.96 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit compute5(m, n)
# 8.35 ms ± 266 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks, going to check it! As mentioned in comments to Divakar's post, I made the mistake of writing "np.sum(result & n)" instead of "np.sum(result & n.ravel())" which wrongly results in a 1D*2D array sum. Intended count is of 1D*1D array. I'll see if I can adjust your code for that.

Comment: @FrancWeser I suspected as much, as it seemed a bit of a strange operation. In any case, I edited the answer with the fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying to the get Python out of the way: convert your columns to bit fields, convert your N to a bit field as well, `&` together each triplet, then use (bin(num).count('1')) (or a proper popcnt if numpy has one).

Comment: Thanks, best language/resource to do this?